# Canvas Y coordinates when coexist with menu

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

this is my first question.

I have this xml code:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" >
    
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_Plik">
            <MenuItem Header="_Zapisz" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Otwórz" Click="MenuItem_Click_1"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

    <Canvas x:Name="myCanvas" MouseDown="myCanvas_MouseDown" MouseMove="myCanvas_MouseMove" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Canvas.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="100"/>
        </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>
</DockPanel>
```

```
        private void myCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                Point newPoint = new Point();


                newPoint = e.GetPosition((this)); // <-wrong Y coordinates

                Line myLine = new Line();
                myLine.Stroke = Brushes.Red;

                myLine.X1 = currentPoint.X;
                myLine.Y1 = currentPoint.Y;
                myLine.X2 = newPoint.X;
                myLine.Y2 = newPoint.Y;
                currentPoint = newPoint;
                myCanvas.Children.Add(myLine);
            }
            
        }
```

In the myCanvas_MouseMove i get Y position about 18 pixel when I click about 0 or 1 Y coordinates. Why menu move canvas Y coordinates in my case?

Comment: Are you sure "this" is that Canvas? If you define that event hander on a Window, "this" is that Window.

Comment: MAESTRO!!!  .... solved :) Thanks